# Take action on the DOM for each Ajax response without freezing the UI

Tags: javascript, ajax, performance

### I perform a `for loop` for each request sent..

```js
for (let j = 0; j <= 1000; j++) {
    $.ajax({
        url: `127.0.0.1/index?value=${j}`,
        method: `get`,
        beforeSend: function() {
            // any action..
        },
        success: function(response, status, xhr) {
            $('#response').append(response);
        }
    });
}
```

However, as long as the for loop is not completed from **0** to **1000** (*may vary, the value 1000 is for illustration only.*) the **user interface is frozen**, and the request responses are not printed in the ***DOM***.

```html
<div id="response"></div>
```

How do I optimize this? at each ajax request, it will be printed the result in the div response dynamically (or synchronously)

Is there any simple solution that I can fit it this?

Comment: Would be a lot more efficient on both ends to make one request with a start and end value

Comment: @Charlietfl How so? do you think the for loop does not fit in this context?

Comment: If you cannot do that, consider making the calls async.

Comment: @Bibberty Would you have a solution for this or if possible you could provide me with a basis? async/await is not my strong

Comment: Less load on server making a single request, no need for long loop to run, correct order of responses will be assured, ui won't freeze etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could call the ajax 1 by 1 like so:

```
const fn = j => $.ajax({
  url: `//127.0.0.1/index?value=${j}`,
  method: `get`,
  beforeSend: function() {
    // any action..
  },
  success: function(response, status, xhr) {
    $('#response').append(response);
    if (j < 1000) {
      fn(j + 1);
    }
  }
});
fn(0);
```

this will, unlike your code, guarantee the order of the results too

with some tweaks, you could do 10 at a time or 20 etc - but, to **guarantee** result order (if that's important) you'll need to make some other changes if you do more than one at a time

Based on the comment - here's a solution where you call `fn` with the first index, last index and how many requests at a time - and the result order is irrelevant

```
const fn = async (index, max, count) => {
    const promises = [];
    for (i = 0; i < count; ++i) {
        promises.push($.ajax({
            url: `//127.0.0.1/index?value=${i+index}`,
            method: `get`,
            beforeSend: function() {
                // any action..
            },
            success: function(response, status, xhr) {
                $('#response').append(response);
            }
        }));
    }
    await promises;
    index += count;
    if (index <= max) {
        fn(index, max, Math.min(count, max + 1 - index));
    }
};
fn(0, 1000, 10);
```

And one more because three is good luck - as above, but keeping result order in sequence regardless which order the results come back in

```
const fn = async (index, max, count) => {
    const promises = [];
    for (i = 0; i < count; ++i) {
        promises.push($.ajax({
            url: `//127.0.0.1/index?value=${i+index}`,
            method: `get`,
            beforeSend: function() {
                // any action..
            }
        }));
    }
    const results = await promises;
    $('#response').append(results.join(''));
    index += count;
    if (index <= max) {
        fn(index, max, Math.min(count, max + 1 - index));
    }
};
fn(0, 1000, 10);
```

Comment: What if I wanted the value of `j` to start from **500** and not from **0**? Would I need to pass it as a parameter or would I break your code (or at least the logic?)

Comment: The order does not matter regardless of any ajax response.

Comment: well, your code starts from 0 and goes to 1000 - if you want to start from 500, then change the function to accepts a starting point - so, you're saying you don't care if you get the results in a random order

Comment: @gleisin-dev - I've added a solution where you can start at any number, end at any number, and specify how many requests can be done at once, and the order of results (within the "count" requests) is not important

Comment: There's a little problem outside... what if I need to abort the ajax request? as I do that if it is within the scope `fn`

Comment: well, how would you do it with your original code

Comment: my original code is basically what is in the question, change something with the parameters, ie `fn(agn, min, max, index, count)`

Comment: your original code doesn't handle aborting ajax requests - so, how could I possibly add that to the answer considering this is the first you've mentioned aborting the requests - perhaps that's an issue for another question rather than changing the goal posts after I've answered the question you asked

Comment: I understand, I'll see what I do here, but thank you very much for your disposition!

Comment: Where does this variable `response` come from `$('#response').append(response.join(''));`

Comment: sorry, typo - was supposed to be results